# get json data from my controller in highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts

I am trying to make a highchart which should show me number of reserved rooms for every type:

Here is my controller with  GetHighChart method:

```
 public JsonResult GetHighChart()
    {
        var viewModel = Reservation.RoomTypeByDate(5);
        var result = new JsonResult { Data = viewModel};
        return result;

    }
```

Reservetion.RoomTypeByDate looks like this:

```
 public static List<dynamic> RoomTypeByDate(int? LunaDorita)
    { 
    var result=DBContext.Current.ExecuteProcedure("RoomtypeCountbydate",
      new QueryParam<int>("@p_ID", LunaDorita.Value)).Map();
    return result;
```

And here is my stored procedure:

```
SELECT Room_Type, COUNT(*) AS NumarRezervari
FROM   dbo.Reservation re
JOIN   dbo.Room ro ON ro.RoomID = re.Room_ID
JOIN   dbo.Room_Type rt ON rt.RoomType_ID = ro.Room_Type_ID
WHERE  MONTH(re.Data_Check_in)=@p_ID
GROUP  BY Room_Type
```

My Json Result is:

```
[[{"Key":"Room_Type","Value":"Double"},{"Key":"NumarRezervari","Value":2}],      [{"Key":"Room_Type","Value":"LUXURY"},{"Key":"NumarRezervari","Value":1}],[{"Key":"Room_Type","Value":"Triple"},{"Key":"NumarRezervari","Value":1}]]
```

How should I modify this javascript file so that instead of the series from below to have my data from my GetHighChart method from myReports controler.So instead of name i want to have my RoomType for example Double and instead of data to have my own data [2,5....]?

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'

           },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false,
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        this.x + ': ' + this.y + '°C';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio you can use [**DotNet.Highcharts**](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) to make building highchart objects much easier.  By doing so you can work with Series and Data objects directly and then just pass them into Highcharts.  It takes the creation of the JavaScript out of the picture.  Below is a sample of how I create my charts in MVC 3.  As you can see I am using LINQ to SQL to gather the required data for the chart.  I am creating a list of Series to hold the data.  This is done dynamically so I can add as many Series as needed for the chart without having to know how many there will be beforehand.  Then I create the chart and pass the list of Series to it.

```
public ActionResult CombinerBarToday(DateTime? utcStartingDate = null,
                                     DateTime? utcEndingDate = null)
{
    //GET THE GENERATED POWER READINGS FOR THE SPECIFIED DATETIME
    var firstQ = from s in db.PowerCombinerHistorys
                 join u in db.PowerCombiners on s.combiner_id equals u.id
                 where s.recordTime >= utcStartingDate
                 where s.recordTime <= utcEndingDate
                 select new
                 {
                     CombinerID = u.name,
                     Current = s.current,
                     RecordTime = s.recordTime,
                     Voltage = s.voltage,
                     Watts = (s.current * s.voltage)
                 };

    //GET A LIST OF THE COMBINERS CONTAINED IN THE QUERY
    var secondQ = (from s in firstQ
                   select new
                   {
                        Combiner = s.CombinerID
                   }).Distinct();

    /* THIS LIST OF SERIES WILL BE USED TO DYNAMICALLY ADD AS MANY SERIES 
     * TO THE HIGHCHARTS AS NEEDED WITHOUT HAVING TO CREATE EACH SERIES INDIVIUALY */
    List<Series> allSeries = new List<Series>();

    TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

    //LOOP THROUGH EACH COMBINER AND CREATE SERIES
    foreach (var distinctCombiner in secondQ)
    {
        var combinerDetail = from s in db2.PowerCombinerHistorys
                 join u in db2.PowerCombiners on s.combiner_id equals u.id
                 where u.name == distinctCombiner.Combiner
                 where s.recordTime >= utcStartingDate
                 where s.recordTime <= utcEndingDate
                 select new
                 {
                     CombinerID = u.name,
                     Current = s.current,
                     RecordTime = s.recordTime,
                     Voltage = s.voltage,
                     Watts = (s.current * s.voltage) / 1000d
                 };


        var results = new List<object[]>();

        foreach (var detailCombiner in combinerDetail)
        {
            results.Add(new object[] { 
                            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(detailCombiner.RecordTime, easternZone), 
                            detailCombiner.Watts });
        }

        allSeries.Add(new Series
        {
            Name = distinctCombiner.Combiner,
            //Data = new Data(myData)
            Data = new Data(results.ToArray())

        });
    }

    Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
    .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Spline, ZoomType = ZoomTypes.X})
    .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Combiner History" })
    .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = "Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in" })
    .SetOptions(new GlobalOptions { Global = new Global { UseUTC = false } })
    .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
    {
        Spline = new PlotOptionsSpline
        {
            LineWidth = 2,
            States = new PlotOptionsSplineStates { Hover = new PlotOptionsSplineStatesHover { LineWidth = 3 } },
            Marker = new PlotOptionsSplineMarker
            {
                Enabled = false,
                States = new PlotOptionsSplineMarkerStates
                {
                    Hover = new PlotOptionsSplineMarkerStatesHover
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Radius = 5,
                        LineWidth = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .SetXAxis(new XAxis
    {
        Type = AxisTypes.Datetime,
        Labels = new XAxisLabels
        {
            Rotation = -45,
            Align = HorizontalAligns.Right,
            Style = "font: 'normal 10px Verdana, sans-serif'"
        },
        Title = new XAxisTitle { Text = "Time(Hour)" },
    })
    .SetYAxis(new YAxis
    {
        Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Kilowatt" }
    })

    .SetSeries(allSeries.Select(s => new Series {Name = s.Name, Data = s.Data }).ToArray());

    return PartialView(chart);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps:
Make chart a global variable

```
var chart;
```

You can define load event to your chart like this

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({    
chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline',
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                    }
                }
            }
```

here requestData is a javascript function. In this function you can bind data dynamically to the chart.

```
function requestData() {

        var pointArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
            //                    var series, shift;

            //                    var point = new Array(new Date(data2[i].UTC).getTime(), parseFloat(data2[i].Value));
            var point = {
                x: new Date(data2[i].UTC).getTime(),
                y: parseFloat(data2[i].Value)
            };
            chartRTM.series[0].addPoint(point);

        }                
        chartRTM.series[0].redraw();}
```

NOTE: Here data2 is a json list of the data to be bound.